# Change color and font for some part of text in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, textbox

Is there a way to change color and font for some part of text which I want to put on TextBox or RichTextBox. I am using C# WPF.

For example

```
 richTextBox.AppendText("Text1 " + word + " Text2 ");
```

Variable word for example to be other color and font from Text1 and Text2. Is it possible and how to do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you just want to do some quick coloring, the simplest solution may be to use the end of the RTB content as a Range and apply formatting to it. For example:

```cs
TextRange rangeOfText1 = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
rangeOfText1.Text = "Text1 ";
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);

TextRange rangeOfWord = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
rangeOfWord.Text = "word ";
rangeOfWord.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
rangeOfWord.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Regular);

TextRange rangeOfText2 = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
rangeOfText2.Text = "Text2 ";
rangeOfText2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
rangeOfText2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
```

If you are looking for a more advanced solution, I suggest reading [this Microsoft Doc about Flow Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview), as it gives you a great flexibility in formatting your text.

Comment: After the object "rangeOfText1", "rangeOfWord" and "rangeOfText2" are complete, how concat them?

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest way I can find!

Answer (score 20):

You can try this out.

```
public TestWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.paragraph = new Paragraph();
    rich1.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);

    var from = "user1";
    var text = "chat message goes here";
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(from + ": "))
    {
        Foreground = Brushes.Red
    });
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(text);
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    this.DataContext = this;
}
private Paragraph paragraph;
```

Use the Document property of the RichTextBox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to first add a line and then color parts of it afterwards, a little change to the answer of @Gimno might help:

```cs
TextRange rangeOfLine = new TextRange(rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd, rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd);
rangeOfLine.Text = "This is a long string";
rangeOfLine.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);

TextRange rangeToColor = new TextRange(rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd.GetPositionAtOffset(-5), rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd.GetPositionAtOffset(-2));
rangeToColor.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

This lets you add a line of text to the rich text box first, which is colored black. After it was added a selection from -5 to -2 according to the end of the content gets colored red.

My string which I add to the RTB gets appended in multiple functions, so it would be quite unhandy if the coloring had to appear for each snippet in the according function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **Document** property of **RichTextBox** and add a **Run** to it.

Document property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx

Run: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have made my own `class` to manipulate `Text`s of `TextBlock`, `TextBox`...

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for text manipulation operations
/// </summary>
public class TextManipulation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Is manipulating a specific string inside of a TextPointer Range (TextBlock, TextBox...)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startPointer">Starting point where to look</param>
    /// <param name="endPointer">Endpoint where to look</param>
    /// <param name="keyword">This is the string you want to manipulate</param>
    /// <param name="fontStyle">The new FontStyle</param>
    /// <param name="fontWeight">The new FontWeight</param>
    /// <param name="foreground">The new foreground</param>
    /// <param name="background">The new background</param>
    /// <param name="fontSize">The new FontSize</param>
    public static void FromTextPointer(TextPointer startPointer, TextPointer endPointer, string keyword, FontStyle fontStyle, FontWeight fontWeight, Brush foreground, Brush background, double fontSize)
    {
        FromTextPointer(startPointer, endPointer, keyword, fontStyle, fontWeight, foreground, background, fontSize, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Is manipulating a specific string inside of a TextPointer Range (TextBlock, TextBox...)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startPointer">Starting point where to look</param>
    /// <param name="endPointer">Endpoint where to look</param>
    /// <param name="keyword">This is the string you want to manipulate</param>
    /// <param name="fontStyle">The new FontStyle</param>
    /// <param name="fontWeight">The new FontWeight</param>
    /// <param name="foreground">The new foreground</param>
    /// <param name="background">The new background</param>
    /// <param name="fontSize">The new FontSize</param>
    /// <param name="newString">The New String (if you want to replace, can be null)</param>
    public static void FromTextPointer(TextPointer startPointer, TextPointer endPointer, string keyword, FontStyle fontStyle, FontWeight fontWeight, Brush foreground, Brush background, double fontSize, string newString)
    {
        if(startPointer == null)throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(startPointer));
        if(endPointer == null)throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(endPointer));
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))throw new ArgumentNullException(keyword);

        TextRange text = new TextRange(startPointer, endPointer);
        TextPointer current = text.Start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        while (current != null)
        {
            string textInRun = current.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textInRun))
            {
                int index = textInRun.IndexOf(keyword);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    TextPointer selectionStart = current.GetPositionAtOffset(index,LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    TextPointer selectionEnd = selectionStart.GetPositionAtOffset(keyword.Length,LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    TextRange selection = new TextRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newString))
                        selection.Text = newString;

                    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, fontSize);
                    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, fontStyle);
                    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, fontWeight);
                    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, foreground);
                    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, background);
                }
            }
            current = current.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
TextManipulation.FromTextPointer(_TextBlock.ContentStart, _TextBlock.ContentEnd, "IWantToBeManipulated", NewFontStyle, NewFontWeight, NewForeground, NewBackground, NewFontSize);
TextManipulation.FromTextPointer(_TextBlock.ContentStart, _TextBlock.ContentEnd, "IWantToBeManipulated", NewFontStyle, NewFontWeight, NewForeground, NewBackground, NewFontSize, "NewStringIfYouWant");
```