# Selective formatting in a TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to do selective formatting in a text box i.e. I actually wanted to change the color of mobile numbers in order to the status of DND?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change color of some text in textbox and not the all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change color and font for some part of text in WPF C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442067/change-color-and-font-for-some-part-of-text-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Comment: yes but according to the DND status when a user click on a button

Answer (score 1):

This may be an overkill, but take a look at the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) class. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-richtextbox/) is a nice tutorial.

Comment: You don't need a `RichTextBox`. Regular `TextBlock` supports formatting of `Inlines`/`Runs`.

Comment: But a TextBlock doesn't support user edits.

Comment: Right, I missed that... :) Um, uh... it might be useful knowledge if edits are not required. :)