# Change color in part of text in textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, string, colors, code-behind

I need change color in code behind for part of text string..

My exaple:

```
textblock1.Text = string1 + string2 + string3;
```

String have dynamic values, and i want to string2 display after running the program in blue color and it must be defined in the code behind.

Its possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

That working

```
                        textblock1.Inlines.Clear();
                        textblock1.Inlines.Add(new Run(string1));
                        textblock1.Inlines.Add(new Run(string2) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
```

Answer (score 6):

I Hope that will help you:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="16">
        <Run Foreground="Red">Your_Text_1</Run>
        <Run Foreground="Orange">Your_Text_2</Run>
        <Run Foreground="purple">Your_Text_3</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but i need it define in code behind because textblock dont show static text, but different numbers of variables with different values :/

Comment: please refer to this answers:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442067/change-color-and-font-for-some-part-of-text-in-wpf-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Run"
Ex :  **"Run Name="Value_from_codebehind" />"**

In the code behind attach the value