# How to change part of text color at RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, textbox, richtextbox

Good day!

I try to change part of text to red color.

So, i try to use TextBox, but it not works.
So, i read, that RichTextBox can do that:[i use this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442067/change-color-and-font-for-some-part-of-text-in-wpf-c-sharp)

But i do not know how to append colored text?

```
  TextRange rangeOfText1 = new TextRange(tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd,    tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd);
 rangeOfText1.Text = "Text1 ";
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
                             rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
```

Ok, i get TextRange, but how to append it to RichTextBox?

Can you tell me how to make some part of text to red color?
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it) [accidentally pasted in wrong link! sorry!]

Comment: Do you want to edit the text or just display it?

Comment: i want to make simple compile error cheching.So, if i found error of compilation- i want to color error text with red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with your example:

```
TextRange rangeOfText2 = new TextRange(tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd,
    tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd);

rangeOfText2.Text = "RED !";

rangeOfText2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty,Brushes.Red);
rangeOfText2.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
```

works for me.

> > Ok, i get TextRange, but how to append it to RichTextBox?

It has already been added with

```
new TextRange(tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd, tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd);
```

What you also can do (I used this myself lately):

```
var fd = new FlowDocument();

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("normal text and this is in "));
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("red") { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(" and this is blue.") { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });

fd.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

tbScriptCode.Document = fd;
```

Comment: may be new TextRange(tbScriptCode.Document.ContentStart, tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd); ?

Comment: If you use TextRange(tbScriptCode.Document.ContentStart, tbScriptCode.Document.ContentEnd); all existing text will be overwritten. Play a bit with all this stuff. I did this myself some weeks ago, where I searched for a quick way to display some text with specific lines displayed in color. I ended with the FlowDocument solution. There may be better solutions, and the one you came up with seems interesting too.