# Change color for some part of text in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My question is related to: [Change color and font for some part of text in WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442067/change-color-and-font-for-some-part-of-text-in-wpf-c-sharp/5442224)

There is an answer that states you can change the text foreground color with this statement:

```
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
```

However, this doesn't work for me: I get a runtime error indicating that the parameter type SolidBrush cannot be used for ForegroundProperty. What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color and font for some part of text in WPF C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442067/change-color-and-font-for-some-part-of-text-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [System.Windows.Media.Brushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes(v=vs.110).aspx) insted of [System.Drawing.Brushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush(v=vs.110).aspx)