# Dynamically, at run-time, how to change the color of some words in a text box in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox, runtime, highlight, text-editor

I am trying to change the color of **some words** inside a text box in WPF, ***at run-time,*** like text editors do, to highlight predefined keywords, such as While.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color and font for some part of text in WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442067/change-color-and-font-for-some-part-of-text-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1):

you could use the foreground property to set the new color like say after pressing a button

```cs
TextBoxName.Foreground = new SolidBrushcolor(colors.Blue);
```